# Uploadify send directly to S3 and save filename to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3, uploadify

I need to use uploadify to allow users to upload files which will be stored in Amazon S3.

I believe it is possible to upload directly to S3 but I also need to do some processing on my server.

What I need to do is generate a unique filename for the video before upload and then save the filename to my database after a successful upload.

Can anyone provide any insight on how to accomplish this?

Comment: What on earth does uploadify mean?

Comment: @Ramhound It's an ajax flash component for uploading files to a server, allows multifile selection. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We also do this in our application.

> What I need to do is generate a unique filename for the video before upload and then save the filename to my database after a successful upload.

I think you've got that the wrong way around.

We have a generic `Post` table where we store all types of Posts, of which `Photo` is one.

So when a user uploads a photo, we first *save* the photo so it get's a unique identifier (e.g the IDENTITY field in the DB - PK), then we use that as the filename.

That way we can use **convention** to render the S3 links - e.g /s3.amazonaws.com/yourbucket/photoid.jpg.

So your controller would look something like this:

```
// might need to change to HttpPostedFileBase[] for multiple file uploads
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase, string photoName) 
{
   var stream = httpPostedFileBase.InputStream;
   var photo = new Photo { Name = photoName };
   repository.Save(photo);
   s3service.Upload(stream, photo.Id);
}
```

Are you allowing the user to enter a name/tags/other input of some sort? If so, you could create unique slugs on the server based on this name, then use that as the filename (good for SEO).

Comment: I am currently doing basically the same thing. However, due to limits imposed by my host, I am unable to upload large files to the web server and then send to S3...so I need to post the file directly to S3 from the browser.

Comment: @stephen776 - Allowing the browser to post directly to S3 seems ripe for abuse.

Comment: I believe that amazon supports posting directly to s3 and a hashing solution is used to secure the parameters being passed. I am looking for more info on this method in conjunction with uploadify

Comment: @stephen776 - okay, well then can't you use JS to generate a guid/identifier, then pass that to the `fileDataName` parameter of the uploadify call, then in the callback, do an AJAX call to your server to save to DB?